# Preventing UIView from switching before UIAlertView appears with Parse (Form not Complete, Logout Yes/No, etc)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, parse-platform

I am currently coding an app that has a login and sign-up page with Parse as the backend. I am able to get the username and all of that registered, but I need help with the code that notifies the user if one of the fields are blank. I want to display the UIAlertView of the error and prevent the view from switching in this case (it switches and then displays the notification that the fields were left blank). I know it's probably something simple. Just need a little help. Here is the code below.

```
-(IBAction)signUpUserPressed:(id)sender
{

PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = self.userRegisterTextField.text;
user.password = self.passwordRegisterTextField.text;



[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FinishSignup" sender:self];
    } else {



        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}];
}
```

Help would be much appreciated on this. This is also similar to if you are logging out of an app and it asks you if you would like to logout- stopping the view from switching and displaying the notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before calling signUpInBackgroundWithBlock: check if the fields are empty yourself.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username =     self.userRegisterTextField.text;
user.password =   self.passwordRegisterTextField.text;

if (user.username.length > 0 && user.password.length > 0) {
    //sign up only if username/password given
    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FinishSignup" sender:self];
   } else {



        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}];
}
}
else {
//show alert that username or password was left blank
}
```